# How to trigger redux form validation

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form, redux-thunk

I have two pages with two redux forms 7.0.3 .The user Enters Search criteria Information into the first page and presses a submit button and then navigates to the next page where they will get some more detailed information about their search .If they press the save button to save their search and this search was done before they will be returned to the first page where an error message will be displayed saying that this is a duplicate search .
I want to be able to trigger the first forms validation and some how put this error message in the error queue so that it is displayed through redux forms .
Any ideas how I could do this .
thanks for your help .